# Ethernet link down issue

Tags: ethernet

We have used an AR8031 PHY IC in our design. We have found the issue with Link is not glowing when do the power cycle for the board and Ethernet communication with the port also not happening. Still, the board is booting completely with no issue.

This issue is observed when the board temperature reaches to around +70 °C.
Note, the MAC, PHY and Ethernet connectors support industrial grade temperature range.

Could you please let us know how to solve this issue?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Sure. Post schematics, PCB layout and code and we can take a look.

Comment: @justme WE don't have the code with us since this code is developed by our customer I can share only schematic of that particular ethernet section. Schematic added in the main post. may I know in which format layout you need?

Answer (score 1):

Worth looking at the spec of the main crystal/oscillator.  I've seen issues where it has too large a tempco, and the ref goes out of range at high temps.

Comment: we have not a observed any deviation in main crystal/oscillator output. The crystal/oscillator output is as expected during the high temperature (issue condition)